# Cross module function scope? Where is it looking

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given the following:

**`include.js`**

```
module.exports = function() {

    ...

    return {
        func: function(val) {
            return Function('return ' + val + ';');
        }
    }
}()
```

**`running.js`**

```
var outer = function() {
    var include = require('./include.js');

    var x = include.func('eq');

    console.log(x(5, 5));
}
outer()
```

...where would I put `function eq(x, y){ return x === y; }` such that this would work? I'm currently getting an  `eval at <anonymous>` on the line that calls the function; x(5,5) in this case.

It doesn't like when `eq` is in `include.js` or when it's in `running.js` ~ I know this is example code is taken from my project and made pretty ambiguous...but, if it's possible, where would that function go?

OR

...would it be better to define an object of functions where the keys are the name of the function?

```
defaultFuncs = {
    'eq': function(x, y){ return x === y; }
}
```

Comment: Almost any time you find yourself considering `new Function`, it is pretty safe to assume there is a better way.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't like it; even if it is for an internal tool ... I think the defaultFuncs object is going to work much much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent scope of functions created via `new Function` is the global scope, not any local or module scope. So

```
global.eq = function(a,b) { return a==b };
function func(name) { return Function("return "+name+";"); }

var x = func("eq");
var equals = x();
equals(5, 5) // true
```

should work.

> ...would it be better to define an object of functions where the keys are the name of the function?

Definitely yes.

Comment: You also might be interested in my [`F.js`](https://github.com/bergus/F/blob/master/F.js), where you'd write `var equals = F("=="); equals(5, 5)`; That might spare you the large repetitive object

Comment: hey, thanks! I decided to go with the functions object because I don't want to clutter the global space. `F.js` should be great, because these functions are "validators" between values and data sets :)